# How to make a true linear quaternion rotation?

Tags: transforms

It turns out to be impossible to make a 360° rotation by using quaternion only with 2 keyframes. So I used three. However, the result appears unlinear, even though the curve interpolation type are all set to Linear. [demo file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ojv5B6Lb-3OEM2NFlKQ09DYjA/view?usp=sharing)

I wonder if this is something unavoidable. If not, is there any way to achieve a true linear quaternion rotation?

Comment: When you say "true linear quaternion rotation" do you mean SLERP? http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/realNormedAlgebra/quaternions/slerp/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would need to make a **sinus/cosinus** graph for that animation to have linear motion with quaternions:

For the 1st cube I set *Euler rotation* and animated a linear rotation, with *Copy rotation* constraint copied that to the second cube and then baked the animation on it with Object > Animation > Bake Action (visual keying on). This resulted in (the gif is little laggy):

[image]

This could be done easily with **Sinusoidal** easing type. Setting correct easingIn/easingOut for keyframes yields to this nice result:

[image]

Comment: It seems this is quite suitable for the current project. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes. We shared similar concept on the easing type. However, If the global and local coordinates are not aligned, it's still better to use baking method. Or some better idea?

Comment: If the rotation is some random angle or combination of multiple linear rotations it's truly best to bake it.

Comment: Yes. Btw, for the attached case, I think another way is to simply use one keyframe with two buil-in function modifier on both curves, which is a possible option, too.  :)

Answer (score 7):

I would use drivers for this. For a simple rotation around a static axis, it's quite straightforward, and the formulae can be entered directly in the driver window. No need for elaborate Python scripts.

A rotation quaternion is composed of four trigonometric values:
`W = cos(a/2)` for clockwise rotation or `W = -cos(a/2)` for counter-clockwise rotation
`X = dirX*sin(a/2)`
`Y = dirY*sin(a/2)`
`Z = dirZ*sin(a/2)`
where `a` is the rotation angle and `dirX`, `dirY` and `dirZ` are the `X`, `Y` and `Z` values of a vector that describes the direction of the axis of rotation. This vector should have a [magnitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitude_%28mathematics%29) of 1, i.e. `sqrt(dirX**2+dirY**2+dirZ**2) = 1`

For linear rotation where 360° takes a known number of frames,
`a/2 = (frame-1)*pi/(number of frames)`
(Blender normally starts at frame 1, and the rotation at the first frame should be 0, hence the subtraction of 1 from the frame number).

In your example file the rotation is around the global Z axis, whose directional vector is `(0, 0, 1)`, and 360° takes 40 frames. This yields the following driver functions. Use the Scripted expression driver type.

`W = cos((frame-1)*pi/40)`
`X = 0`
`Y = 0`
`Z = sin((frame-1)*pi/40)`

[image]

In this image, I'm actually rotating around the Y axis in front view, but the basic idea is the same.
[image]

There are several methods to calculate the values of `dirX`, `dirY` and `dirZ`. I will try to explain two of them.

### Method 1

You need to know the angles between the axis of rotation and the global X, Y and Z axes. Let's call these angles `aX`, `aY` and `aZ`. Then it's as simple as
`dirX = cos(aX)`
`dirY = cos(aY)`
`dirZ = cos(aZ)`
These are the [direction cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine) of the axis, and if the angles are composed correctly, the vector `(dirX, dirY, dirZ)` will have a magnitude of 1. If it doesn't, the angles define an axis that can't exist in 3D space.

### Method 2

Find the coordinates in the object's **local space** where the axis of rotation intersects the surface of the object. Let's call them `x`, `y` and `z`. The vector `(x, y, z)` will have a magnitude that *may* be 1, but quite possibly isn't. To normalize it, simply divide it by its own magnitude. Like this (dividing a vector by a [scalar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_%28mathematics%29) is the same as dividing its individual values by that scalar):
`dirX = x/sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)`
`dirY = y/sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)`
`dirZ = z/sqrt(x**2+y**2+z**2)`

A more in-depth explanation of the math behind all this, is most likely off topic here, but it probably would be right at home at [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

I've found the following links quite useful:
[Using Quaternion to Perform 3D rotations](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/3d/quaternions.html)
[Quaternions and spatial rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation)

Comment: Thank you very much for such comprehensive answer. I think it may help people quite a lot. :)

Comment: @LeonCheung Math is my only true love, so this is an answer I enjoyed writing quite a lot. :)

Comment: I must confess, that although math is my true love, 3D geometry has never been my highest priority, and I'm just getting the hang of quaternions. I made an error in my original answer. The error was of little consequence; I said that the direction cosines needed to be normalised to a magnitude of 1. That isn't true, because they should already have a magnitude of 1, and normalising them would make no difference. Nevertheless, I've corrected the error.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by answers from SixthOfFour and Jerryno, I optimized the curve with the relatively new [Robert Penner Easing Equations](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.71/Animation) feature, set type to **Sinusoidal**, which saves quite a lot keyframes.

[image]

**[example file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ojv5B6Lb-3WDdwMmR6MmVkZ2M/view?usp=sharing)**