# How do I ensure a sequence of quaternions from matrix.decompose() is continuous?

Tags: python

It seems that blender's Matrix decompose() function can exhibit some numerical "instability".  What I mean is that orientation matrices that are relatively close can have significantly different elements in their quaternion matrix that makes interpolated keyframing unusable.

The following simple python script will calculate a sequence of matrices representing rotations around the Z axis in a smooth manner.  It then decomposes the matrix into a quaternion, and inserts that as a keyframe.  When you view the resulting fcurves in blender you can see that the Z value jumps from -1 to 1 about halfway through the animation.

```
import bpy
from math import *
from mathutils import *

def matrix_for_time(t):
    theta = 2 * pi * t
    mat = Matrix([[cos(theta), sin(theta), 0],
                  [-sin(theta), cos(theta), 0],
                  [0, 0, 1]]).to_4x4()
    # for illustration we use rotation about Z axis,
    # but in the arbitrary case, the orientation could be for a pine cone bouncing down a hill.
    return mat


def mission(obj):
    res = 36
    qs = QuaternionStabilizer()
    for z in range(res):
        mat = matrix_for_time(z/res)
        (loc,quat,scale) = mat.decompose()

        obj.rotation_quaternion = qs.stabilize(quat)
        for ai in range(len(quat)):
            obj.keyframe_insert(frame=z*5, data_path="rotation_quaternion", index=ai)


mission(bpy.context.active_object)
```

[image: fcurves resulting from python script]

" [How to make a true linear quaternion rotation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23727/how-to-make-a-true-linear-quaternion-rotation) " has some screenshots that imply quaternions aren't necessarily discontinuous.

Is there a technique for blender's python API to get a sequence of quaternions that can be keyframed and interpolated without discontinuity?  For bonus points: link to an article that explains this mathematical oddity and why decomposition works this way.

This technique should be usable with arbitrary orientation matrices, because they are calculated from something a little more complex than this simple Z rotation (in my specific case I'm flying along a bezier curve).

Comment: http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/  ; specifically the code example and the discussion of the "trace" seems important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing a little more research I think I have found a technique that will work.  Examining the matrices that are computed from the quaternion led me to conclude that q and -q both represent the same orientation, so I compare both q and -q to the previous quaternion orientation and pick whichever one is closest in 4-space.  The following udpated code sample illustrates the technique:

```
import bpy
from math import *
from mathutils import *

def mission(obj):
    res = 36
    qs = QuaternionStabilizer()
    for z in range(res):
        theta = 2*pi *z / res
        mat = Matrix( [ [ cos(theta), sin(theta), 0],
                        [ -sin(theta), cos(theta), 0],
                        [ 0,0,1]]).to_4x4()
        (loc,quat,scale) = mat.decompose()

        obj.rotation_quaternion = qs.stabilize(quat)
        for ai in range(len(quat)):
            obj.keyframe_insert(frame=z*5, data_path="rotation_quaternion", index=ai)


class QuaternionStabilizer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.old=None

    def stabilize(self, q):
        if self.old is None:
            rval = q
        else:
            d1 = (self.old-q).magnitude
            d2 = (self.old+q).magnitude
            if (d1<d2):
                rval = q
            else:
                rval = -q
        self.old = rval
        return rval

mission(bpy.context.active_object)
```

And now my fcurves don't look discontinuous:
[image: quaternion fcurves]

This will not give good results if your orientations are flailing about wildly, but that's a case of Garbage In Garbage Out.

Comment: I don't want to waste your time, but it would be nice if you could explain the math and the code a bit to learn from it :)

Comment: Well, the most advanced math in there is where I compute the Z rotation matrix.  That's covered by http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations .  The decomposition of quaternions is a pretty heavy subject and is covered by the link in my comment under the original question.  I don't fully understand the math behind quaternions myself, but I know enough to recognize some situations where they are being abused.

Comment: Since the rotated vector p' is  q * p * q^-1 and the scalar multiplication by -1 is commutative, q and -q should represent the same rotation.

Answer (score 2):

I fiddled around with the [Quaternion(axis, angle) constructor](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/mathutils.html?highlight=mathutils.quaternion#mathutils.Quaternion) and  [Quaternion.slerp](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/mathutils.html?highlight=mathutils.quaternion#mathutils.Quaternion.slerp) but both gave non-continous results as well. 
(Quaternion.slerp worked using a third value inbetween though)

But you might use the formula given on this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Using_quaternion_rotations):

> cos(θ / 2) + sin(θ / 2) * 
>   (u<sub>x</sub> * i + 
>    u<sub>y</sub> * j +
>    u<sub>z</sub> * k)

where θ is the rotation angle and u = (u<sub>x</sub>, u<sub>y</sub>, u<sub>z</sub>) the unit vector for the rotation axis.

```
import bpy
import math
from mathutils import Quaternion

obj = bpy.context.active_object
action = obj.animation_data.action

def from_axis_angle(axis, angle):
    half_angle = angle / 2.0
    scalar = math.cos(half_angle)
    factor = math.sin(half_angle)

    return Quaternion((
        scalar,
        axis[0] * factor,
        axis[1] * factor,
        axis[2] * factor
    ))

def set_rot_kf(frame, quat, action):
    for fcu in action.fcurves:
        if fcu.data_path == "rotation_quaternion":
            index = fcu.array_index
            fcu.keyframe_points.insert(frame, quat[index])

axis = (0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
angle = 2.0 * math.pi

frame_start = 0
frame_end = 60
dt = frame_end - frame_start
frac = 1 / dt

for frame in range(dt + 1): 
    quat = from_axis_angle(axis, frame * frac * angle)
    set_rot_kf(frame_start + frame, quat, action)

    #or
    #quat *= dq 
    #where
    #dq = from_axis_angle(axis, frac * angle)
```

The result looked like this, where you can see the graphs of cos(θ / 2) and sin(θ / 2) from 0 to 2π:

[image: graph]

Comment: While this technique seems appropriate for axis/angle rotations, I need a solution that works with arbitrary orientation matrices (as I stated in the question: I am driving along a bezier curve)