# full single rotation last pass strange behavior (incomplete X / Z rotation)

Tags: animation

I have a strange behaviour of the pass between 2 last keyframes of X and Z axis in full single rotations - instead of snapping the original state the model rotates backwards, both in Blender and c++ code? where can the problem  presumably be? I, not that deep into Blender to guess the reasons myself:( Applying the recorded video describing the said above - thank you :)
https://youtu.be/tw0JBH1Bobo

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the way quaternions work.  To perform a single rotation from `q=(1,0,0,0)` around axis `(0,0,1)` it will go from `(1,0,0,0)` through `(0,0,0,1)` and return to its original orientation as `(-1,0,0,0)`.  Now it may seem strange to start at `(1,0,0,0)` and end at `(-1,0,0,0)` and still be in the same orientation, but that is just the way quaternions work.  `q` and `-q` represent the same orientation.

Since you aren't ending your spin at `(-1,0,0,0)` that means the animation system animates the figure unspinning instead of completing the spin.

I first realized these properties of quaternions back in 2014 shortly after I asked [How do I ensure a sequence of quaternions from matrix.decompose() is continuous?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/how-do-i-ensure-a-sequence-of-quaternions-from-matrix-decompose-is-continuous?noredirect=1&lq=1) .  Take a good look at the difference between the fcurve screenshot in the question and the screenshot in the accepted answer.

Comment: thank you, mate, I manully changed W component of the root bone quaternion of the last keyframe to -1.0 (it was 1.0f after copying from the first pose, as well as creating the last pose manually) - and the rotation works complete - thanks again :)